# Replace a single character in the text between two brackets

Tags: bash, sed

```
http://website/2015,4-5; Title; Description [23-01, Nr, 2015,4/5]
```

I have a bash script with similar lines like here above.
It starts a website `http://website/2015,4-5` and saves it with Firefox as `Description [23-01, Nr, 2015,4/5]`.

The forward slash in its file name is where it goes wrong; does anyone have suggestions how to work around this?

I like to replace text with sed and already replaced 2015/ with 2015, just replacing all forward slashes results in url not functioning anymore.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear (yet), not least because you don't (yet) show your desired output.  However, if the objective is to replace all slashes between the square brackets with (for sake of concreteness) dashes, then this `sed` script can be used.

#### Variant A: a single slash

```
sed -e 's%^\(.*\[[^]/]*\)/%\1-%'
```

This captures `\(…\)` everything from the start of the line `^` to a square bracket `\[` followed by any number of non-slashes, non-close square brackets `[^]/]*`, all of that followed by a slash, and replaces it with the captured material and a dash.

#### Variant B: multiple slashes

This requires a `sed` loop to repeatedly do the replacements:

```
sed -e ':again' -e 's%^\(.*\[[^]/]*\)/%\1-%' -e 't again'
```

The first `-e` argument creates a label `again`; the second `-e` argument is the substitution regex exactly as before; the third `-e` argument is a conditional jump back to the label `again` if a substitution was made.

#### Example Output (Variant B)

```
$ echo "http://website/2015,4-5; Title; Description [23-01, Nr, 2015/4/5] / x23" |
>     sed -e ':again' -e 's%^\(.*\[[^]/]*\)/%\1-%' -e 't again'
http://website/2015,4-5; Title; Description [23-01, Nr, 2015-4-5] / x23
$
```

The trailing `/ x23` is there simply to demonstrate that the changes made by the script are bounded by the square brackets.  If you add several sets of square brackets with slashes inside, then all those slashes are replaced with dashes.

Some versions of `sed` (GNU `sed`) may allow you to group the three `-e` expressions into a single argument.  Other versions won't.  The version shown should work with any version of `sed`.  It doesn't use extended regular expressions either (because there's no urgent need for them, and because the options to activate them vary between versions of `sed`).

Answer (score 0):

Using gawk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*)(\[[^]]+\])(.*)/,a) { gsub("/","",a[2]); $0=a[1] a[2] a[3] }1' file
http://website/2015,4-5; Title; Description [23-01, Nr, 2015,45]
```

The `match()` above just extracts the block of text between `[...]` into `a[2]` (and puts the text before/after it into `a[1]` and `a[3]` respectively) and removes all `/`s within that block before putting the line back together.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue and wanted to let you know about it.
Just found out that there were already reponses with more or less the same solution and some explenation about it, this is what I used and with your explenation I start the understand it even better. Thanx

sed -e :1 -e 's@([.*)/(.*])@\1,\2@;t1'